# Hiding jQuery Supersized gallery in a responsive design?

Tags: jquery, supersized

I'm using the [Supersized jQuery plugin](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) and am trying to 'disable' or hide the fullscreen images when the screensize is smaller than 480px i.e. around the iPhone size. However, I can't see a way to do it - I've tried with CSS without success (trying to hide the #supersized ul list), but I can't get it to work as the style is inline.

I've copy-pasted the HTML generated by Supersized for the first list item used in the gallery so you can see what I have to work with - might there be a callback I could use or something?

```
<ul id="supersized" class="quality" style="visibility: visible;">
   <li class="slide-0 prevslide" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;"><a target="_blank"><img src="#" style="width: 1425px; left: 0px; top: -190.5px; height: 869.25px;"></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks,

Osu

Comment: Doesn't it work: $('#supersized').hide() ?

Comment: Hi @roasted - unfortunately not, but if I add !important to my classes, it seems to work ok i.e. overrides. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add !important to my class declarations in order for it to work i.e.

```
#supersized { display:none !important; left:-999999px !important; }
```

Comment: If you set an !important css-property, the jquery-script isn't able to override your css. But !important isn't working in older browsers. With an iPhone there is no problem

Comment: Why you are moving your element with left? What happens if you set {visibility:hidden!important;} instead of {display:none!important;}?

Comment: @algorhythm - For some reason, that display:none doesn't work, I had to 'move' the image out the way and override the background colour as well. Thanks for the tip on !important btw